# eclipse IDE exceeding java heap space - windows XP

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing android apps using eclipse running on windows XP. Recently eclipse has been complaining about running out of heap space for itself. It brings up a window like this:

[image]

which appears without even running my app. I.e. I just start eclipse, wait a minute and this window pops up. On another forum I saw a suggestion of starting up eclipse with `eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xmx512M`, but the problem still appeared.

My eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

EDIT: I just changed this part:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
```

to say:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
```

But the crash still happened.

Comment: Try running with `--clean` option.

Comment: http://edwards.sdsu.edu/labsite/index.php/daniel/236-increasing-heap-size-in-eclipse

Comment: @Raghunandan: The article you linked to is about running out of heap **for programs run from eclipse ** - not for eclipse itself.

Comment: @Mick It is for eclipse not for programs, I tried to post the same as answer, but when I saw his comment I have discarded my answer..increase memory in eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option you want to increase is not the permanent size, but the heap size - set the -Xmx384m option to f.e. -Xmx712m .

Comment: Looks like this has fixed the problem - why Xmx means "heap" I'll never know!

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html - it's a non-standard (hence the X) option that sets the max (hence mx) heap size.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to set these value on eclipse config
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

Answer (score 0):

Some times setting -Xms and -Xmx values might not work if there isn't enough memory available in the system. 
I generally use -xms 128m - (The initially memory which is allocated when eclipse is launched)
and  -xmx 512m - (Maximum allowed memory for the eclipse) which increase gradually as the heap size increases. This is sufficient for normal usage but you can increase the maximum value to almost 1380m( on a 4gb machine more than this might not work some times).
To monitor how the heap is growing in eclipse you can use **Window->Preferences-General->Show Heap Status.**